# Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Linux flavor) run script on wifi up

Tags: python, linux, networking, raspberry-pi, sh

Currently I am experience issues with the script automatic run after wifi adapter connects to a network.

After ridiculously extended research, I've made several attempts to add script to a /etc/network/if-up.d/. Manually my script works; however it does not automatically.

User permissions:

```
 ls -al /etc/network/if-up.d/*
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  703 Jul 25  2011 /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  484 Apr 13  2015 /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-daemon
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4958 Apr  6  2015 /etc/network/if-up.d/mountnfs
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  945 Apr 14  2016 /etc/network/if-up.d/openssh-server
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   48 Apr 26 03:21 /etc/network/if-up.d/sendemail
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1483 Jan  6  2013 /etc/network/if-up.d/upstart
 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 Sep 17  2016 /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant -> ../../wpa_supplicant/ifupdown.sh
```

Also, I've tried to push the command directly in /etc/network/interfaces
by adding a row

```
post-up /home/pi/r/sendemail.sh
```

Contents of **sendemail.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
python /home/pi/r/pip.py
```

After the reboot, nothing actually happen. I've even tried **sudo** in front

I assume that **wpasupplicant** is the thing which causes that, but I cannot get how to run my script in **ifupdown.sh** script under /etc/wpa_supplicant.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have no connectivity prior to initializing the wifi interface, I would suggest adding a cron job of a bash or python script that checks for connectivity every X minutes.

Ping (host);

If host is up then run python commands or external command.

This is rather ambiguous but hopefully is of some help.

Here is an example of a script that will check if a host is alive;

```
import re,commands


class CheckAlive:
def __init__(self):
        myCommand = commands.getstatusoutput('ping ' + 'google.com)
        searchString = r'ping: unknown host'

        match = re.search(searchString,str(myCommand))

        if match:
            # host is not alive
            print 'no alive, don't do stuff';
        else:
            # host is alive
            print 'alive, time do stuff';
```

Comment: Thanks Madison! Suggested approach might help in a certain way (e.g. currently, I've added a script in the '/etc/profile' and it runs after login and only once), but the thing is: cron job should be managed separately otherwise, the script will run continuously (which is not the aim itself). The main purpose is to run it if the wlan0 is up and the ip is obtained over DHCP.

Comment: Ok I see your point, I think you are on the right track, 
in  /etc/network/interfaces try adding;

`auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp
    post-up /usr/local/sbin/my-custom-script`

But replace with your actual interface and script.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I originally did, but had no effect. I reckon that wpasupplicant steals the thread.